# Update a property in all Vertices in Gremlin

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin, tinkerpop3, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi, gremlinnet

I want to update the value of a property in all vertices of one label.

```
g.AddV('car').property('id','1').property('name','Benz')
g.AddV('car').property('id','2').property('name','BMW')
g.AddV('car').property('id','3').property('name','Audi')
g.AddV('car').property('id','4').property('name','Nissan')
```

Like that there are 1000s of vertices. I want to update the `name` value to lowercase in all those vertices. It needs to run on Azure Cosmos Graph DB.

Answer (score 1):

Since gremlin doesn't have string manipulation functions.

And as far as I know, CosmosDb does not support lambda steps.

I think you will have to fetch all the names and ids:

```
g.V().has('name').project('id', 'name').by(id).by('name')
```

then lowercase every name in your code. and then update it like this:

```
g.V(id).property(single, 'name', lowercaseName)
```

Or all in one query:

```
g.inject(1).union(
.V(id1).property(single, 'name', lowercaseName1),
.V(id2).property(single, 'name', lowercaseName2)
.V(id3).property(single, 'name', lowercaseName3)
....
)
```

example: https://gremlify.com/pizsh5s293/1

Comment: The provided example doesn't update vertices properly. When a query is executed, the name of the car is still the same

Comment: @Serlok thanks, I edited the example